# Saving objects in array for highscore list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, storage

I'm making a hangman game with JQuery/Javascript and now I want a highscore table. My thought was to create an array of objects but the problem is that when I try to store the game result as an object (playername:playerscore pair) in an array my text output is "object Object" instead of the values.

```
var playerName;
var playerScore;
var gameResult = {};
var highscoreList = [];


function toHighscoreList() {
    playerName = $('#nameTag').text();   // for example value "Henry"
    playerScore = guessedWrong.length;   // for example value 3

    gameResult = {player: playerName, score: playerScore};
    highscoreList[highscoreList.length] = gameResult;

    $('#score1').text(highscoreList[0]);
};
```

I also tried this version with the same result:

```
function toHighscoreList() {
    playerName = $('#nameTag').text();   
    playerScore = guessedWrong.length; 
    gameResult = {player: playerName, score: playerScore};

    localStorage.setItem('gameResult', JSON.stringify(gameResult));

    $('#score1').text(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameResult')));
};
```

Is there another way to store several key:value pairs? I still want the highscore list to be easily modified so I can use the sort() method for ranking and replace lower scores with higher.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO and thumbs up for this beautifully formatted question. P.S: if `highscoreList[highscoreList.length]` >> lenght is `1`, you're than trying to get `highscoreList[0]` Use simply `highscoreList.push( gameResult )` to stack your objects into the `highscoreList` Array.

Comment: Also what is not clear is `guessedWrong.length; // 3` that's seems basically a wrong approach if you're looking for a Number like `5`, using `length` will return the characters length `65432 = 5`

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but does the list has maximum length? What are the rules for a score to be in the list? Does it keep a single high score per player or does it keep all time best scores?

Comment: @plalx probably a list and than you calculate a TOT at the end of the table... at least I'd do it like that :)

Comment: Alcually I don't see and advantage of sorting, I'd simply keep track of a lits of played games and as I've said in my previous comment - do a Winner calculator.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working now! The list should be for 10 scores, with the lowest scores (guessedWrong.length = number of wrong guesses until finish) first. I would preferably like to store the results as "all time bests" in localStorage as in the second version of my function above, but it doesn't return my values, only object Object. Any ideas about that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to sort you highscores, so try:

```
var playerName;
var playerScore;
var gameResult = {};
var highscoreList = [];

function toHighscoreList() {
    playerName = $('#nameTag').text();   // for example value "Henry"
    playerScore = guessedWrong.length;   // for example value 3

    gameResult = {player: playerName, score: playerScore};
    highscoreList.push(gameResult);
    highscoreList.sort(function(a,b) { return (b.score - a.score ) });

    $('#score1').text(highscoreList[0].player + " - score: "+ highscoreList[0].score);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With "highscoreList[0]", you are getting the first object stored in the array. You should take care of getting individual value (like highscoreList[0].player or highscoreList[0].score), format and print it.

$('#score1').text(highscoreList[0]);

can be replaced with

$('#score1').text(highscoreList[0].player + ' has scored ' + highscoreList[0].score);